# Por quê não insere no banco de dados?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Por que o seguinte código de inserção no Banco de Dados não funciona? O código chega até o Joption "chegou!"

```
private void btnCadastroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente(id, nome, nascimento, cpf, sexo, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade,estado, data_entrada, preco_pagamento, datapagamento, mespago)VALUES (12, "+txtNome.getText()+", 1222-10-20, 12312, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123,23, 123, 123, 123, 123)";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "chegou?", "chegou?", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    try {
        pst = conecta.prepareStatement(sql);;
        pst.executeQuery(sql);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastrado", "Cadastrado", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } catch (SQLException error) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Da algum erro? Deve estar retornando erro, mas você tem um catch que não serve pra nada no código. Adicione a seguinte linha dentro do `catch`: `error.printStackTrace();`

Comment: @diegofm discordo, serve sim, serve para esconder o erro e dificultar a solução :)

Comment: não da erro não, vc clica e ele aparece o primeiro aviso, mas não insere

Comment: deu esse erro org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Não pode utilizar métodos de consulta que pegam uma consulta de um comando preparado.

Comment: Sou novo aqui kk desculpa!

Comment: O erro está te denunciando o problema, o método `executeQuery` é para consultas de `select`, insert deve-se usar o `executeUpdate`

Comment: já tentei e continua com o mesmo erro..."não pode utilizar os metodos"

Answer (score 1):

Está a falhar porque você está a usar o método incorreto para executar o query (devia usar `executeUpdate()` em vez de `executeQuery()`), e também porque está a passar o `nome` e o `nascimento` como *código SQL* em vez de *valores SQL*. Ou seja, fora de aspas. Seria melhor usar parâmetros no `PreparedStatement`, por exemplo:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente " +
             "(id, nome, nascimento, cpf, sexo, endereco, numero, bairro, " +
             "cidade,estado, data_entrada, preco_pagamento, datapagamento, "+
             "mespago) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst = conecta.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, 12);
pst.setString(2, txtNome.getText());
pst.setString(3, "1222-10-20");
pst.setInt(4, 12312);
// ...
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Mais informação sobre os métodos `executeQuery()`, `executeUpdate()`, `setInt()`, `setString()`, etc. está no [API da `PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Se faz sentido no seu programa, pode fixar algumas parâmetros no código SQL. Mas se for de certos tipos, por exemplo `VARCHAR`, `DATE` ou `TIMESTAMP`, é preciso por entre aspas (`'`):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente (id, nome, nascimento, cpf) " +
             "VALUES (5, 'Fulano', '1222-10-20', ?)";
```

Mas é muito mal ideia tentar simplesmente acrescentar uma string que vem do utilizador ao seu código SQL:

```
// XXX NAO FAÇA ISSO!
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente (nome) VALUES ('"
           + txtNome.getText() + "')";
```

porque assim admite possibilidade da [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL). E em geral não é nada preciso nem conveniente porque já existe o método `setString()` na `PreparedStatement`.